# Why can I not assign characters to my character array after it has been initialized with a string literal?

Tags: c++, arrays

Here is the code, when I run this code using CodeBlocks10.05 compiling with GNU GCC with no flags, I do not get the results which I hoped for. I was hoping that all the characters in the array would be changed to a `'z'` if it was not set by one of the characters in the initial string literal or the null terminator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    char stringVar[10] = "Hello";
    //char stringVar[10] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
    //char stringVar[10] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
    //char stringVar[10] = {};

   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
       if(stringVar[i] != 'H' and
           stringVar[i] != 'e' and
           stringVar[i] != 'l' and
           stringVar[i] != 'o' and
           stringVar[i] != '\0')
       {
            stringVar[i] = 'z';
       }
   }

   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
       cout << (int)stringVar[i] << "\t" << (char)stringVar[i] << endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Here is my output:

```
72      H
101     e
108     l
108     l
111     o
0
0
0
0
0
```

Here is what I expected:

```
72      H
101     e
108     l
108     l
111     o
0
122     z
122     z
122     z
122     z
```

So what am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char stringVar[10] = "Hello";
```

Initialize first 5 to `Hello` an rest to `\0`, so your if condition will be false

```
if(stringVar[i] != 'H' and
   stringVar[i] != 'e' and
   stringVar[i] != 'l' and
   stringVar[i] != 'o' and
   stringVar[i] != '\0') <<------ this condition will always return false, so you can't modify `stringVar`
```

Comment: You are correct, the program works as intended now. I do not know why I was not realizing that the number zero is the null terminator character. Taking out that condition yields the desired results. I was hoping I could use this code to figure out precisely how the compiler initializes the array in the various commented out methods. Thanks!

Comment: @Leonardo If you take out the condition, then element at **5th** index is not **0**. Are you sure that is what you want ? Your expected output says otherwise.

Comment: @Mahesh well, it does not work as I originally hoped it would, but now that I understand it better it works as "expected". To be honest I am unsure how I can make it output my original expectation.